# For loop only calling on the last array in the object in some places and not others

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, for-loop

I'm calling on an object array from a JSON file:

```
if (results !=null && results.value !=null {
  for (var i = 0; i < result.value.length; i++) {
    time = results.value[i].starttime;
    place = results.value[i].location;
    who = results.value[i].attendee;
    console.log("first test", time, place, who);
  }
}
function(error) {
   alert ("Error here" + error.message);
}
$(#homepagetime).html(time);
$(#homepageplace).html(place);
$(#homepagewho).html(who);
console.log("second test", time, place, who);
```

The console log named "first test" successfully displays every result from the json in the following way:

```
12:00 India Gandhi
14:00 England Elizabeth
16:00 USA Obama
```

This is exactly what I'm looking for but when I for the bellow code to display the results in the homepagetime, homepageplace, and homepagewho divs, nothing appears. And for the console log "second test" I only get back the first array in the object and not the remaining e.g.:

```
12:00 India Gandhi
```

It's clearly only calling on the first array in the object but I can't understand why considering the for loop specifies all the arrays. I'm still learning JavaScript.

Comment: What is `results.value`?

Comment: @ASDFGerte results.value is the name of the json I'm calling on

Comment: You need to put `results` value in the question

Comment: Are you sure the second `console.log` logs the first element, and not the last?

Comment: My mistake, yes! It's logging only the last one. But why is that? @ASDFGerte

Comment: Your loop overwrites the variables on every iteration, until it is finished. Then you check the variables, so, they have the values from the last iteration.

Comment: I'm starting to understand what's going on now, thank you. Do you think you could help with a code sample to support this?

Comment: `let str; str = "first this"; str = "now that"; console.log(str); for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) { console.log("overwriting str!"); str = \`${i}\`; } console.log(str);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your (display) code must be inside the loop ou you can use a string concatenation or the append() function to append data to div elements

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.value.length; i++) {
    time = results.value[i].starttime;
    place = results.value[i].location;
    who = results.value[i].attendee;
    console.log("first test", time, place, who);
    $(#homepagetime).append(time + '<br>');
    $(#homepageplace).append(place + '<br>');
    $(#homepagewho).append(who + '<br>);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code that displays the results is outside the loop, that means it will only execute once and not for each array element like intended. The variables time, place, and who are being set on each loop iteration and what you're left with at the end is the result of the last iteration. Note that even if you move the display code to inside the loop, the html function replaces the content currently on the element, so, each loop iteration would replace the result and you'd end up with the same content as you have currently. I suggest either concatenating  the results or dynamically creating a new element for each.

Answer (score 1):

You should append html in loop where you assigning the values. Out of loop you  will get the last value due to closure.

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.value.length; i++) {
    time = results.value[i].starttime;
    place = results.value[i].location;
    who = results.value[i].attendee;
    console.log("first test", time, place, who);
    $(#homepagetime).html(time);
    $(#homepageplace).html(place);
    $(#homepagewho).html(who);
  }
```